# Show api-blueprint documentation of my REST API doesn't work

Tags: php, zend-framework3

I've the following situation: I built a REST API using zend (not apigility but single packages like zf-rest).
Now I want to document my API (the endpoints, request and response types etc.). For this purpose I created a folder "data" and a subfolder "api-blueprint" under my project directory. Here I stored some files with markdown. So I have:

```
/myproject/data/api-blueprint/index.md
/myproject/data/api-blueprint/hal-entry-point.md
...
```

My expectation is that I can open a browser and call

```
mydomain.com/api/rest/myproject
```

(this is the root) and see the content of hal-entry-point.md, so I get an overview about the supported endpoints. But I can't get it to work. Is there a special framework which I forgot to install or a configuration of zf-rest, zf-hal ...?